# as-create-or-update-trigger: command not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I download the Auto Scaling Tool here:

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2535

When I tried to create a trigger, the command not found. I also export its environment, but command that not found.. I tried to find that as-create-or-update-trigger folder, but there is no file like that. What's up?

> root@ip:/root/tools# as-create-or-update-trigger Trigger1
>   --auto-scaling-group AutoScale --namespace "AWS/EC2" --measure CPUUtilization --statistic Average --dimensions
>   "AutoScalingGroupName=AutoScale" --units "Percent" --period 60
>   --lower-threshold 30 --upper-threshold 70 --lower-breach-increment"=-1" --upper-breach-increment "1" --breach-duration 120 OK-Created/Updated trigger
>
> as-create-or-update-trigger: command not found

Does anyone has the same issue? Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that command is now deprecated and replaced by 
auto scaling policies and cloudwatch alarms.

There is some documentation on how to do this here:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been deprecated in favor of "mon-put-metric-alarm"